# Java Generics: Foo<T>, Foo, Foobar<T extends Foo<T>> and Foobar<T extends Foo>

Tags: java, oop, generics, extends, generic-type-argument

In Java Generics, given a generic class/interface `Foo<T>`,
What's the difference between declaring a new generic class:
`Foobar<T extends Foo<T>>` or simply `Foobar<T extends Foo>`, also why can I instantiate a generic class `Foo<T>` without instantiating the type parameter `T`?, i.e. why can i write the following:
`Foo var = new Foo();`, does this mean that the class is instantiated with an object, through which i can only use the non-generic method?
please forgive me if the question is not so clear, the example i was working on is the following:
`MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo<T> {}
```

is your class.

```
Foo yourVariable = new Foo();
```

equals `Foo<Object> yourFoo = new Foo<Object>();`

```
class Foobar<T> extends Foo {}
```

equals `class Foobar<T> extends Foo<Object> {}`

**the answer to your question**

```
class YourClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {}
```

means YourClass's type `T` is able to compare itself to **objects of T** (its class), whereas

```
class YourClass<T extends Comparable> {}
```

's type `T` is able to compare itself to **objects of class Object**, which is not what you want

Comment: I know my comment is too late now but thanks a ton anyway!